# html video player doesn't load without a refresh

Tags: html5-video, video-player, pjax

html5 player **doesn't load without a refresh** .. how to fix this?

```
    <!--IsvideoFileStart-->
    
<link class="dplayer-css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dplayer/dist/DPlayer.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dplayer/dist/DPlayer.min.js"></script>
<div class="nexmoe-item">
    <div class="mdui-center" id="dplayer"></div>
</div>
<script>
    const dp = new DPlayer({
        container: document.getElementById('dplayer'),
        lang:'zh-en',
        video: {
            url: '<!--FileDownUrl-->',
            type: 'auto'
        }
    });
document.getElementById('dplayer').load();
</script>
        
<!--IsvideoFileEnd-->
```

plz help me, thank you!

Comment: `document.getElementById('dplayer').load();` definitely won't work, since DIV element do not have `load()` method.

Comment: The question is not about **javascript** or **html**, but specifically about **pjax**. You should edit your tags

Comment: Do you use pjax inside Yii or what? What is your stack?

Comment: player dosent load .. i need to manually refresh the page to load player

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload it by running `$.pjax.reload({ container: '#dplayer' });`

Comment: thanks for the reply, i try this .i think i do it wrong, i am a noob :/


`<script>
  const dp = new DPlayer({
  container: document.getElementById('dplayer'),
    lang:'zh-en',
        video: {
         url: '<!--FileDownUrl-->',
          type: 'auto'
      }
     
    });
 $.pjax.reload({ container: '#dplayer' });
</script>`
 



added

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pjax@0.2.8/pjax.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pjax@0.2.8/pjax.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @error404 Well, no reason to add both scripts since it's the same code, only the second one is minified

Comment: ah ok,   but `$.pjax.reload({ container: '#dplayer' }); `  dosent work.